# With IntelliJ Idea and SonarLint I getting error while connecting to SonarQube server

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

The current configuration:

- latest IntelliJ Idea Community Edition (2018.1.4)
- latest SonarLint addon for Idea (3.4.2.2586)
- SonarQube v6.7 (build 33306)

When I try to add the SonarQube server address (authentication with usr/psw) I got this message:

> Failed to connect to the server. Please check the configuration.
>   Error: Fail to request
>   `https://<sonarqube_server_url>/sonar/api/system/status`

But when I try to open this URL (`https://<sonarqube_server_url>/sonar/api/system/status`) from Chrome I got this:

```
{
  "id": "oTvPjWRbAMXWalmApGYG",
  "version": "6.7.0.33306",
  "status": "UP"
}
```

So it seems to be running well, and of course I can log in and use well the webUI.

How should I connect to it from Idea?

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace of the error? It should be in the logs in the Sonarlint tool window.

Comment: You are using the same user in both cases?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes, of course.

Comment: Is your server SSL certificate trusted?

Comment: @agabrys Sorry, I was wrong, the SSL certificate is not verified. Can I configure SonarLint to accept it anyway?

Comment: @BálintBabics Did you find any solution?

Comment: @YoK Unfortunatelly the only way if you delete the certification check from the plugin source, but you should repeat this process in every plugin update.

Comment: That is a tedious option. For us, as SonarQube is only accessible within the intranet, we are now running it without SSL. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be caused by untrusted SSL certificate. SonarLint does not permit the configuration of certificates, but you can add certificate to JRE or JDK. Read more here: [How to add certificates to SonarLint in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37989370/4944847)

Comment: Unfortunately due to a firewall issue I can only reach the SonarQube server through an untrusted URL so I can't add the certificate, because it's not valid.

Comment: You can try add `-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true` to JDK process.

Comment: @Yok please create a new question and include SonarLint Console logs.